# Block spider bot except one

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site where every day in different hour a spider bot scan my site with semrush.

I can block the user agent via htaccess but now at Sunday I scan with semrush my site for some improvement.

So if I block semrush user agent I block myself, IP is every different because It's from semrush.

Is there any way to block all semrush user agent except mine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule  to block the user agent, plus this  excludes your IP and does not block you with that user agent.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} semrush [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^yourIP$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: Sure but when I scan with semrush my Ip can change because I'm using semRush